# c++ linker error : undefined reference to a static function

Tags: c++, linker-errors

A.h file

```
class A{
      public:
      static int* func (int &b);
}
```

A.cpp

```
int* A::func(int &b){
   //some definition here
}
```

I am calling the above function in some other file. I have included the .h file in that. When I try to compile I get the following error

undefined reference to A::func(int &)

Comment: Are you supplying the compiled object code of `A.cpp` (let's call it `A.obj`) to your linker?

Comment: @Als Yes, I have linked the cpp file.

Comment: Post the command you use to compile this file.

Comment: I think first you should get a compiler error of making `A::func()` as `private`! The link error could be due to not linking `A.o` file.

Comment: Do you perchance wrap the file in `namespace Something { ... }`?

Comment: @iammilind Sorry, I did not mention that it is public

Comment: @paddy How would wrapping the stuff in a name space make difference?

Comment: If the class declaration or implementation are in different namespaces, they wouldn't match at linking.  However, there is no compile warning on A::func, so they probably match.

Comment: Can you provide the full A.h and A.cpp files, complete with #includes?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks right.

The first thing to check is that your build environment compiled and linked in A.cpp.